# Drift condition (Markov chains)

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Consider the the forward recurrent time process; i.e. jumps from $0$ to $x+1$ with probability $f(x)$ and from $x+1$ jumps to $x$ and then to $x-1$ and so on until a return to zero.

Let $f(x)=\exp(\alpha x) $.
a) Find $V=[0,\infty)$,  $b<\infty$ such that
$$\Delta V(x)\leq -f(x)+b\chi_C(x).$$
where $\Delta V(x)=PV(x)-V(x)\;\;\text{and}\;\; PV(x)=\int_\Omega V(y)P(x,dy)$ and $C=\{0\}$

b) Can we conclude on how $K^n$ (where $K$ is the kernel function) converges to $\pi$ (what is $pi$) in norm $||\cdot||_f=\sup_{f:|f|<=1}||\cdot(f)||$?

My approach:
If I choose $V$ and $b$ such that
 $$V(x)=\frac{e^{\alpha}}{e^{\alpha}-1}(e^{\alpha x}-1)\;\;\; \text{and}\;\;\;b=\phi(\alpha)=\sum_x e^{\alpha x}f(x)$$
question a) can be written  as 
 $f(x)+ PV(x)\leq V(x) +b\chi_C(x)$ 
where $PV(x)$ is a conditional expected value ie $PV(x)=E(V(X_1)/X_0=x)$

Now from here i'm blocked. Your help  is very appreciated.

For question b) just need a starting point( I know that $K^n(x)=E(V(X_n)/X_0=x)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just take $V(x)=x$ then the expected change in V is just -1 if x>0. What is it if x=0?

Comment: The drift condition then gives some generic estimate for the rate of convergence to the stationary distribution, in terms of the two constants entering into the inequality and the size of the bad set C.

Comment: @Ian, thanks for you response, If $x=0$  the expected change is $0$ and the inequality holds (1>=0).  Could you please give further details on how you got $-1$, what's $b$ in this case? thanks.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding about the expected change. If $V(x)=x$ and $x>0$ then the change in $V$ starting at $x$ is just $-1$ (deterministically), so the average is also $-1$. Starting at $x=0$ you instead have that the average of $V$ is the average of the distribution given by $p_{0,k}$, so that the drift condition hinges on this average being finite. But if $p_{0,k}=Ce^{-\alpha k}$ for some $\alpha>0$, then this average is definitely finite.

Comment: Yes you are right i am having trouble with the expected change if you could  provide me with any useful document on that.  Could you also  explain question b) how the kernel $K^n\to\pi$, and how $\pi$ is ? (say i am a beginner that's why)

Comment: I mean any reference about stability in Markov chains will have this stuff, for example Meyn and Tweedie.

Comment: I also don't exactly understand what you are asking about $K^n \to \pi$. You can compute $\pi$ by just solving the system of equations for it; you have $\pi(x)=p_{0,x} \pi(0) + \pi(x+1)$ for $x>0$. Iterating this recursion to infinity gives you $\pi(x)$ for all $x>0$ as a multiple of $\pi(0)$ (which is not known yet). Then you choose $\pi(0)$ to normalize the whole thing.

Comment: I do not think that it is trivial to determine the convergence *rate* of $K^n$ to $\pi$. This would require you to know some eigenvalue of $K$, which might be hard to calculate (I'm not sure, I didn't try it). One can estimate this convergence rate using the two coefficients in the drift inequality. The details of the latter estimate should be in Meyn and Tweedie somewhere.